# Label polygons with count of intersecting points in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter, geoserver-css-module, cql

I have two spatial layers in a GeoServer instance - polygons (administrative boundaries) and points (resource locations) - and would like to define a layer style (ideally using the CSS format) which labels each of the polygons with a count of the points found within it. This is somewhat similar to the [PointStacker](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/transforms.html#point-stacker) function but using irregular polygons rather than a regular grid.

I've installed the [querylayer](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) module for cross-layer filtering and made a start on the CSS style definition, referring to examples like [these](https://doc-geonode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/006_adv_workshop/001_adv_data_mgmt/002_pretty_maps/cross_layer_filter.html). This style is applied to the polygon layer and successfully filters that to show only polygons which intersect with points in the point layer ('geonode:point_layer').

Now I'd like to extract the **count** of those intersecting points (found within each polygon) and use that to define the `label` as well as to scale the `mark-size` parameter. Below is the CSS definition so far and a rough sketch of what I'm hoping to achieve.

```
[INTERSECTS(the_geom, collectGeometries(queryCollection('geonode:point_layer', 'the_geom', 'INCLUDE')))] {
  mark: symbol(circle);
  mark-size: 12px;
  stroke: #000000;
  label: count;
  label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
}
```

[image: Example polygons labelled with count of intersecting points]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: A workaround would be to precompute the count per polygon or to create a database view.

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton for the welcome and link to the site tour.

Comment: And thanks very much for your suggestions @JakobMiksch - I can't precompute as it needs to be dynamic (new points added often) but the database view looks like a great solution. GeoServer has a [SQL-based view](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) option that I'm exploring now. Thanks again.